# Number format always returns exception

Tags: java, number-formatting

I have the following code

```
private boolean isRightMoneyValue(String value, String currencyIso) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(currencyIso);
        NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
        try {
            currencyFormatter.format(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The input to this function is "1234567898.06789" as value and "EUR" s currencyIso.
The method is always resulting in exception.
Not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: which exception? can you add message at least?

Comment: You're asking it to *format* a value... but that value is already a string. Try passing in a `BigDecimal` instead... or use `parse` instead of `format`.

Comment: And don't swallow `Exception` in your code, at least log the exceptions !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Formatter#format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format-double-) method expect double value. So, you should pass double value instead of `String`.

```
 private static boolean isRightMoneyValue(double value, String currencyIso) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(currencyIso);
    NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
    try {

        currencyFormatter.format(value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Than call this mehod like,

```
  boolean isValid = isRightMoneyValue(1234567898.06789,"EUR");
```

Comment: The number can be of any subclass of Number.

Comment: @anirudh, Yes, that is another way to check.

Comment: When i use your code i get the result after format ¤ 123,456.99. I dont know what is this ¤  symbol coming...